# Fitnesse Suite fails to execute tests

Tags: fitnesse

I'm attempting to run a suite of Fitnesse tests however I keep getting the following error message.

Testing was interupted and results are incomplete.
Test Pages: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions     Assertions: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions

The two pages run fine by themselves however when the links are included on a suite page they don't appear to be getting detected.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Have you clicked on the blue info sign in the upper right corner? You will probably see some exception output. Update your question with that output.

Comment: Thanks GrGr I've been banging my head on this type of thing and never noticed that link! Surprisingly, it tells me exactly what was wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include a page into another page only the text of the page is included, not the attributes.  Pages marked as Suite do not execute as tests unless they are also marked as Test.  If you mark your Suite page with the Test attribute as well your included tests may run (though this depends a lot on what is in those test pages of course!)

I'm also guessing that the two pages you are "linking" into the test are not underneath the suite page (i.e. SuitePage.TestPageOne; a.k.a. sub-wiki) but are elsewhere in the wiki (i.e. SomeOtherPage.TestPageOne).  If this is the case you may also want to move your test pages so they are directly underneath your suite page.  This is what is referred to as a sub-wiki.  [You can find out more about them here](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SubWiki).

Hope That Helps

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the "Prune" checkbox on the page properties got checked.  It has a very similar impact.  prune is intended to allow turning off sections of the suite so the don't run.

Interestingly enough, prune has no effect on child trees or nodes if they are run directly.