# Fitnesse Suites not executing tests below them

Tags: java, fitnesse

This is very similar to the following question: [Fitnesse Suite fails to execute tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913196/fitnesse-suite-fails-to-execute-tests)

However, I am getting this problem inconsistently, I have some suites that will execute the tests below them, and others that will not.

All of the tests are defined as direct children of the suite executing them and have the test property set. All of the Suites are defined as suites.

As mentioned above, this seems to be inconsistent. Some suites will execute the tests below them, while others will not.

Can anyone give me a recommendation on how to solve this problem or how to look into solving it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the Suite-properties if the "Pruned"-checkbox is unchecked?